# ¿Cómo relacionar tres tablas en Laravel usando una de las tablas como tabla pivote?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

Quisiera hacer una relación de tres tablas usando una tabla pivote entre ellas...

Tabla 1 (tbl_lista_contactabilidad)

-id

-usuarios_id

("usuarios_id" debería estar relacionada con asesor_id en la Tabla 2)

---

Tabla 2 (tbl_equipo_postventaatc) "Pivot Table"

-id

-asesor_id

("asesor_id" debería ser el "pivote" entre usuarios_id y id de la tabla users para hacer la relación con la tabla 1 y tabla 2)

---

Tabla 3 (users)

-id

-name

---

Quiero hacer esta relación, he tratado de esta manera pero no lo he conseguido... (Pondré solo las relaciones de cada modelo)

Tbl_Lista_Contactabilidad (Model 1)

```
public function postventaatc(){

return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tbl_EquipoPostventaatc','usuarios_id');

}
```

Tbl_Equipo_Postventaatc (Model 2) -> Este debería ser el pivote modelo

```
public function contactabilidad(){

return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tbl_Lista_Contactabilidad','usuarios_id');

}

public function user(){

return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','asesor_id');

}
```

User (Model 3)

```
public function postventaatc(){

return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tbl_Lista_Postventaatc','asesor_id');

}
```

Comment: quisiera hacer una relación de tres tablas... usando una tabla intermedia que sirva como tabla pivote

Comment: pues, cuando intento hacer la relación no la toma... supongo que es por algun error de la relación o simplemente no sé como hacer una relación de tres tablas a través de una tabla pivote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procede de está forma:

- El método que se usa es **`belongsToMany`**
- Elimina el modelo de la tabla pivote, no hay razón para que dicha tabla tenga esa representación
- En los modelos **`users`** y **`(tbl_lista_contactabilidad)`** establece la relación, indicando como argumento el nombre del modelo al que apunta la relación
- Pasa como segundo argumento el nombre de la tabla pivote pues no sigue las convenciones de Laravel y necesitas indicarlo
- Tus tablas no siguen las convenciones por lo tanto debes de matar su nombre en cada modelo
- Edita tu modelo de la tabla contactabilidades, es muy raro y no convencional el nombre que le das, (Checa el nombre que le daré mas abajo)
- Cómo también tu llave primaria y foránea no siguen las convenciones revisa aquí sobre el [tercer y cuarto parámetro](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Código

```
protected $table = 'tuTabla';
```

**EDICIÓN**

- El modelo `users` debe tener una relación del siguiente modo:

Código

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function contactabilidades()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Contactabilidad::class, 'tbl_equipo_postventaatc', 'asesor_id');
    }
}
```

- El modelo `Contactabilidad` deberá tener una estructura como la siguiente:

Código:

```
class Contactabilidad extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'tbl_lista_contactabilidad';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'tbl_equipo_postventaatc', 'asesor_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por responder amigo... lo he hecho de esta manera.. para ver si te entendi

Comment: Model Tbl_Equipo_Postventaatc ----------------------- public function usuarios(){

 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User','Tbl_Equipo_Postventaatc');

}------------------------- Model User ---------------  public function postventaatc(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tbl_Lista_Contactabilidad','Tbl_Equipo_Postventaatc');

}

Comment: al intentarlo de esa manera me genera este error ---------QLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'bduempresas.tbl_equipo_postventaatc' doesn't exist (SQL: select `users`.*, `Tbl_Equipo_Postventaatc`.`tbl__lista__contactabilidad_id` as `pivot_tbl__lista__contactabilidad_id`, `Tbl_Equipo_Postventaatc`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id` from

Comment: Revisa mi edición

Comment: si... cada model esta marcado con su respectiva tabla.... fué mi error este es el verdadero error que me da ------------ SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tbl_equipo_postventaatcs.tbl__lista__contactabilidad_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.*,

Comment: Creo que está faltando un parametro... he visto varios modelos many to many y tienen otro parámetro a parte que debería usar ya que no estoy utilizando la convencion... pero he intentado colocarle otros... como usuarios_id de la tabla tbl_lista_contactabilidad y me sigue generando error

Comment: con tu repsuesta me genera el siguiente error ------------ QLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tbl_equipo_postventaatcs.user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.*, `tbl_equipo_postventaatcs`.`asesor_id` as `pivot_asesor_id`, `tbl_equipo_postventaatcs`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id` from `users` inner join `tbl_equipo_postventaatcs` on `users`.`id` = `tbl_equipo_postventaatcs`.`user_id` whe

Comment: muchas gracias... he encontrado la solución gracias a tu respuesta, una pregunta... para que los modelos funcionen tienen que estar relacionados en la base de datos de igual manera??? o solo con los modelos es suficiente para hacer la relacion?